# How to turn this ruby string into a normal array?

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays

i'm retrieving a string that looks like this:

```
"[[[256, 498]]] [[[256, 498]], []] [[[256, 498]], [], []] [[[256, 498]], [], [], []]"
```

How can I make it look like this?

`[[256,498],[256,498],[],[256,498],[],[],[256,498],[],[],[]]`

Looking for a solution in either ruby or JavaScript.

Comment: Is that supposed to be valid array syntax?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still looking for a more elegant solution but this will work

```
str.scan(/\[+(\d*, ?\d*)?\]+/).flatten.map do |a|
  a ? a.split(",").map(&:to_i) : []
end
#=> [[256, 498], [256, 498], [], [256, 498], [], [], [256, 498], [], [], []]
```

Breakdown of the methodology

```
scanned_string_array = str.scan(/\[+(\d*, ?\d*)?\]+/)
#=> [["256, 498"], ["256, 498"], [nil], ["256, 498"], [nil], [nil], ["256, 498"], [nil], [nil], [nil]]
scanned_string_array.flatten
#=> ["256, 498", "256, 498", nil, "256, 498", nil, nil, "256, 498", nil, nil, nil]
scanned_string_array.flatten.map do |a|
  #if a is nil return empty array otherwise split on comma and map to Integer
  a ? a.split(",").map(&:to_i) : []
end
#=> [[256, 498], [256, 498], [], [256, 498], [], [], [256, 498], [], [], []]
```

**Update:**

Found a more elegant way or at least I like it better

```
str.scan(/\[+(\d*),?\s?(\d*)?\]+/).map do |a|
  a.reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
end
#=> [[256, 498], [256, 498], [], [256, 498], [], [], [256, 498], [], [], []]
```

Comment: That looks plenty elegant as it returns a valid array definition.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you. I was looking for a way to handle the `,` better. I updated my post with a solution that I find more elegant.

Comment: @Jay It might be worth noting that while I like the second method better visually the first method is faster by ~10% +/- 1%. Although depending on the frequency of this method and the size of the string the difference may be inconsequential.

Answer (score 1):

I would extract the array as follows.

**Code**

```
def extract(str)
  str.scan(/\[[^\[\]]*\]/).map { |s| s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) }
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "[[[256, 498]]] [[[256, 498]], []] [[[256, 498]], " \
      "[], []] [[[256, 498]], [], [], []]"
extract(str)
  #=> [[256, 498], [256, 498], [], [256, 498], [], [], [256, 498], [], [], []]
```

**Explanation**

For the above example:

`str.scan` extracts all strings of the form `"[...]"`, where `...` are characters other than opening and closing braces:

```
a = str.scan(/\[[^\[\]]*\]/)
  #=> ["[256, 498]", "[256, 498]", "[]", "[256, 498]",
  #    "[]", "[]", "[256, 498]", "[]", "[]", "[]"]
```

`map` then passes each element of `a` to its block, and assigns that value to the block variable `s`, the first being:

```
s = "[256, 498]"
```

The following operations are then performed:

```
ss = s.scan(/\d+/) #=> ["256", "498"] 
ss.map(&:to_i)     #=> [256, 498]
```

When `"[]"` is passed into the block:

```
s = "[]"
ss = s.scan(/\d+/) #=> []
ss.map(&:to_i)     #=> []
```

**Benchmark**

I've had a request for a benchmark comparison of methods.  I am pleased to accommodate that request, and report the results below.  Alas, my solution did not fare that well, but that always seems to happen when the request for the benchmark comes from a certain engineer whose last name contains no vowels (other than the "sometimes y").

I just did one benchmark test, but the results were similar when I varied the test data.

**Methods compared**

```
module Methods
  def smnky1(str)
    str.scan(/\[+(\d*, ?\d*)?\]+/).flatten.map do |a|
      a ? a.split(",").map(&:to_i) : []
    end
  end

  def smnky2(str)
    str.scan(/\[+(\d*),?\s?(\d*)?\]+/).map do |a|
      a.reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
    end
  end

  def cary(str)
    str.scan(/\[[^\[\]]*\]/).map { |s| s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) }
  end
end

@methods = Methods.instance_methods(false)
include Methods
def compute(m, str) send(m, str) end
```

**Benchmark code**

```
require 'benchmark'

@indent = @methods.map { |m| m.to_s.size }.max

def test(str, reps)
  exit if answers_not_all_the_same(str)
  Benchmark.bm(@indent) do |bm|
    @methods.each do |m|
      bm.report m.to_s do
        reps.times { compute(m, str) }
      end
    end
  end
end

def answers_not_all_the_same(str)
  same = @methods.map { |m| compute(m, str) }.uniq.size > 1
  puts same ? "all don't match" : "all match"
end
```

**Results**

```
str = "[[[256, 498]]] [[[256, 498]], []] [[[256, 498]], " \
      "[], []] [[[256, 498]], [], [], []]"
reps = 100_000
puts "Example string, #{reps} repetitions"
test(str, reps)

Example string, 100000 repetitions
all match
             user     system      total        real
smnky1   1.830000   0.000000   1.830000 (  1.830457)
smnky2   1.920000   0.010000   1.930000 (  1.920094)
cary     2.750000   0.000000   2.750000 (  2.752946)
```

Comment: Mind benching this against mine? I am away from a computer. If not I'll do it tomorrow. I am always impressed with your ability to find another way to handle an issue.

Comment: @engineersmnky, your wish is my command.

Comment: Thank you. It always amazes me that ruby and it's following prides themselves on clean clearly written code and while none of these methods "smell" per say the "dirtiest" of them all (in my opinion) preforms the fastest. I would up vote again if I could for the overall completeness of your answer.